# what does this error suggest?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks, malloc

When I am trying to execute my program Its getting error like this -

```
sendip: malloc.c:4631: _int_malloc: Assertion `(unsigned long)(size)
 >= (unsigned long)(nb)' failed
```

Tried capturing error through valgrind,got this one -

```
   HEAP SUMMARY:
   ==3335==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 2 blocks 
   ==3335==   total heap usage: 111 allocs, 109 frees, 7,929 bytes allocated
   ==3335== 
   ==3335== 4 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
   ==3335==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
   ==3335==    by 0x8049EEF: main (sendip.c:435)
   ==3335== 
   ==3335== 20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
   ==3335==    at 0x40268A4: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:236)
   ==3335==    by 0x4031F57: ???
   ==3335==    by 0x804A338: main (sendip.c:521)
   ==3335==
```

Line no. 435

```
              datalen = stringargument(gnuoptarg, &datarg);
      /*This is the line*/ data=(char *)malloc(datalen);
                            memcpy(data, datarg, datalen);
```

If needed I could add other pieces of code ... but help me getting out of this ??? What is this I am getting no clue ..

Comment: It kind of sounds like your program is just running out of memory. How large is `datalen`?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. In my case, I am allocating memory for 2d arrays dynamically and at some point, I get this error. I check my memory usage and I still got more than 25% memory when the error appears, my guess is that my memory gets fragmented, and so there is no more contiguous space to allocate new array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be overwriting "data" and forgetting to free the old content... have you checked this?

Answer (score -3):

glibc's `malloc()` prepends metadata (e.g. the length of the chunk, the pointer pointing to the previous chunk, ...) to the chunk returned to caller, so when overwriting "data", it is easy to corrupt the metadata.